# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel

these are my codes for route and controller

routes:

```
Route::get('/form/create','MyformController@create')->name('form');

Route::post('form', 'MyformController@store');
```

controller:

```
public function create()
{
    return view('formsubmitted'); 
    //i have put form.create as shown in a laravel tutorial
    //but it was showing an error that view form.create is not found, hence i  
    //changed it to formsubmitted(i created that form)
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validateData = $request->validate(
        [
            'Full Name'=>'required',
            'Email'=>'required',
            'Feedback'=>'required',
        ]);
    form::create($request->all());
}
```

I am new to laravel and doing the task of creating a feedback form and storing user info and answer to a database.
I hope to hear from you guys soon. Thank you

Comment: um can you format the codes? it's extremely hard to check and debug it. use control + k. or the () icon on the editor

Answer (score 0):

`/form/create/` and `form` are two different routes. If you want the same route for the GET and POST function, the routes have to be the same.

```
Route::get('/form/create','MyformController@create')->name('form');
Route::post('/form/create', 'MyformController@store');
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is rest api then it might me authentication issue

goto VerifyCsrfToken.php and add there your url for eception
for eg.

protected $except = [

```
    '/anyotherurl',
    '/api/userlist'
];
```